# Tab Icon change default color on iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitabbar

I want to change color in tab icon default color (blue).I have done with iOS5 using tint color.but tint color is not supported on iOS 4.please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the iOS version

```
float version = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if (version >= 5.0) {
    // Adjust tint color
}
```

Older verions don't allow to change the tint color

Comment: is there any alternative for tint color in ios4 ?

Comment: As far as I know, you should then create your own image and make your own button. In my app I just took the default for ios < 5

Comment: you have used default tab in your app for ios < 5

Comment: Maybe check this topic too, haven't read it completly through, but it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274473/how-to-tint-uibarbuttonitem-background-color

Comment: No it is completely different.i want to change tab icon color.default color is blue.